# May i know how do we capture the screenshot of android run in AWS Device Farm using Appium Java TestNG?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testng, testng-eclipse, aws-device-farm

After execution of the test run in AWS Device Farm. The test run was successful but i am unable to see the screenshots and performance of that run. The below messages are displayed in those fields.

1. Screenshots : No Screenshot found
2. Performance : No Performance Data found

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow below instructions to generate the screenshots?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html#test-types-android-appium-java-testng-screenshots

If you cannot get screenshots with those steps. Please attach your appium log and test run url so we could take a close look:)

Comment: Actually we are integrating zip file into AWS device farm and .apk file also. Once run is completed. we are unable to see the Screenshots and Performance of the application and the proper output also. In the logs the Test field is showing empty.

Comment: We need more information to assist. Please reach out either via the AWS Device Farm forum at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193 or through AWS Developer Support.